# jQuery fade + replace issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am brand new to javasript and jQuery, and I'm trying to make a simple script to fade out an image and replace it with a random one.

The following works when the next image to be faded is not referred to as "curImg". I thought maybe my nextImg function was failing to produce, but it appears to be preparing an accurate image location string (why I have the alert function).

Anywhere you see my error(s), I'd appreciate any help! thanks so much, and sorry for the novice level code XD.

```
 $.fn.preload = function() {
        this.each(function(){
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        });
    }

    function nextImg() {
        var curImg = "images/";
        var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
        curImg += randomNumber;
        curImg += ".jpg";
        alert(curImg);
        $([curImg]).preload();
    }

    nextImg();

    $("document").ready( function() {
        $("#umom1").animate({
            opacity: 0
            }, 1900,function() {
            $("#umom1").attr("src", curImg);
            $("#umom1").animate({
                opacity: 1
                }, 1900);
            });


    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a variable scope issue, `curImg` is not defined in global scope, it's defined in local function scope, so you can't access it from anywhere other than the function itself.

Because you used the `var` keyword within the `nextImg()` function, the variable's lifetime is restricted to that function only.

I suggest returning the `curImg` variable from `nextImg()`, like so:

```
function nextImg() {
   var curImg = "images/";
   var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
   curImg += randomNumber;
   curImg += ".jpg";
   alert(curImg);
   $([curImg]).preload();
   return curImg;
}
```

Your `ready` function should then look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img = nextImg();
    $("#umom1").fadeOut(1900, function() {
       $("#umom1").attr("src", img);
       $("#umom1").fadeIn(1900);
    });
});
```